# Bind one row cell with multiple rows cell for excle sheet in panda jupyter notebook

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet like this.

[image: excelsheet]

If I search using the below method I got only 1 row.

```
df4 = df.loc[(df['NAME '] == 'HIR')]
df4
```

[image: output]

But I want to get all rows connecting with this name (same for birthdate and place).

**expected output:**

[image: expected output]

How can I achieve this? how can I bind these things

Comment: Can you paste the top excel data instead of an image will be easy to reproduce.

Comment: ipython notebook link https://drive.google.com/file/d/12AVO0qGsBBw4hbnCsdk1RrMnMOwVwryo/view?usp=sharing @venky__

Comment: excel sheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VHXLS3xusTU9F6oecvTcTPlUfTvplHzZan50DcvXin8/edit   @venky__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forward fill the data with `ffill()`:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan) # in case you don't have null values, but you have empty strings
df['NAME '] = df['NAME '].ffill()
df4 = df.loc[(df['NAME '] == 'HIR')]
df4
```

That will then bring up all of the rows when you use `loc`. You can do this on other columns as well.

Comment: cols = df.columns[:].tolist()
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('', np.nan).ffill() . thank you this solved my problem.

Comment: @Bhagi20 , great I will update my answer. I know what you mean by your code. `df = df.replace('', np.nan)` is a little bit easier.

Comment: yes. can you tell me one more thing. what is a better way to write an excel sheet above way or this way (IMG link. like all hobbies in one cell with a comma seperation) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OdI3tDtOwY_kyTjkKaDTz7XjRehsz9AK/view?usp=sharing ? i want to apply all types of operations like value_counts() etc. 
  @david-erickson

Comment: @Bhagi20 not super easy but not too bad. I would post a brand new StackOverflow question. You are going to want to groupby name and aggregate HOBBY AND COURSE to a list. `df4.groupby(['NAME'].agg({'NAME' : 'list', 'COURSE' : 'list', 'BIRTHDATE' :'first'})` It would look something like that. Again I would post a new question though.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to remove those blank rows in your excel. then fill values by the previous value

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('so.xlsx')

df = df[~df['HOBBY'].isna()]
df[['SNO','NAME']] = df[['SNO','NAME']].ffill()
df

    SNO NAME    HOBBY   COURSE  BIRTHDATE   PLACE
0   1.0 HIR DANCING BTECH   1990.0  USA
1   1.0 HIR MUSIC   MTECH   NaN NaN
2   1.0 HIR TRAVELLING  AI  NaN NaN
4   2.0 BH  GAMES   BTECH   1992.0  INDIA
5   2.0 BH  BOOKS   AI  NaN NaN
6   2.0 BH  SWIMMING    NaN NaN NaN
7   2.0 BH  MUSIC   NaN NaN NaN
8   2.0 BH  DANCING NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: cols = df.columns[:].tolist()
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('', np.nan).ffill() . thank you this solved my problem.